# This is for Excel. I need to make a list, but I want to make a data entry form that will add it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a home page, and 9 other sheets on my excel document. On my home page, I want a button that will allow me to add a set of data (e.g. name: surname: email:).

On this home sheey, it will act as a logbook, so everything I add with that button will be added to the home sheet, as well as to the specific sheet that the data is for, so for example. I need to add a complaint list. then that complaint will go to the home sheet as well as the complaint sheet, and no other sheet. If i add a compliment, that compliment will show on the home sheet as well as the compliment sheet.

Is any of this possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Is any of this possible?

**Yes, it is entirely possible.** <-- That is a full and complete answer to the only question you have asked.

> *'... it will act as..'*, *'...  will be added to ...'*, *'... I need to add a ...'*, *'... will go to the ... as well as the ...'*, *'If i add a ... that ... will show on the ... as well as the ...'*.

These are not questions. They are collectively a [software requirements specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_requirements_specification).

In fact, I'm almost positive that most, if not all, of what you want to accomplish is readily available somewhere on the internet as a sample workbook.

If you get started on your project and run into trouble **within a specific area** then post some sample data, your existing VBA code or worksheet formula(s) and some detail of the singular trouble you are having and someone here should be able to help you.

A wide description of a multi-faceted project is just that; a project and not a specific problem. This venue is intended to help overcoming specific problems that people run into once they put in the individual effort to at least start what they are trying to accomplish.

If you're not willing to put in that effort, then just go hire someone to do your work for you.

<sub>p.s. I apologize if as a *'new contributor'*, you think this is rude, snarky or condescending. GFYY.</sub>

Comment: It is fine now. I first didn't know what to ask for, but once I found out what I exactly needed, I went on to Google and searched. 

For my problem. I needed to add a button, and then in the VBA, assign the button to show a form which I also created in the VBA.

Comment: Don't know and don't care who upvoted this but thanks.